# Packet capture on Android x86, any ideas?

Tags: android-x86

how can I run packet capture on my virtual machine (VMware-android 4.3)?

tried more and more to do, facing the same run-time error : 
"Unfortunately, packet capture has stopped".

just to note that my host machine internet connection is based on Mobile USB tethering by PdaNet application.

Answer (score 0):

The most reputable software I am aware of would be [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/).  The software is open-source and they have detailed documentation on their [wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/) and [docs](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/) page, as well as free online [tools](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/).  For the full list of downloads available -- including 3rd party builds -- go to this [download](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) page instead of the default one.

Comment: I specifically prefer packet capture because it has own decryptor with HTTPS protocols, so you don't need any skills to do this like WireShark.